# Compute the characteristic function of Wiener Process (Brownian Motion).

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Wiener process is a stochastic process $(W_{t})_{t\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}}$ on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ satisfying the following properties:

$(1)$ $W_{0}\equiv 0$;

$(2)$  For $t>s\geq 0$, $W_{t}-W_{s}$ is independent of $\sigma(W_{r}, r\leq s)$;

$(3)$ $W_{t}-W_{s}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,t-s)$;

$(4)$ All paths are continuous, i.e. $W_{t}$ is a continuous function in $t$.

**I am now trying to write out an explicit formula of the characteristic function of Wiener process.**

My idea was to write out the joint distribution and then get some density function if possible, but I got stuck.

Below is my attempt:

Since $W_{t_{i}}-W_{t_{i-1}}$ is Gaussian with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma^{2}=(t_{i}-t_{i-1})$ and since the increments $$W_{t_{1}}-W_{t_{0}}, W_{t_{2}}-W_{t_{1}},\cdots, W_{t_{n}}-W_{t_{n-1}}$$ are independent, we know that $$\mathbb{P}[W_{t_{i}}-W_{t_{i-1}}\leq \alpha_{i}, i=1,\cdots,n]=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(t_{i}-t_{i-1})}}\int_{-\infty}^{\alpha_{i}}e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2(t_{i}-t_{i-1})}}dx.$$

Now, I want to do a linear change of variables to ge the joint distribution of $(W_{t_{1}},\cdots, W_{t_{n}})$, but I don't know how to do it..

Also, even if we retrieve the joint distribution of $(W_{t_{1}},\cdots, W_{t_{n}})$, it seems that we cannot write out the explicit formula for the characteristic function since we don't know the density..

What can I do? Is there another way to write out the characteristic function? Thank you!

**Edit 1:**

Okay I think I progressed a little bit:

Let $0=t_{0}<t_{1}<t_{2}<\cdots<t_{n}<\infty$. Then note that 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^{n}\lambda_{j}W_{t_{j}}&=W_{t_{1}}\Big(\sum_{j=1}^{n}\lambda_{j}-\sum_{j=2}^{n}\lambda_{j}\Big)+W_{t_{2}}\Big(\sum_{j=2}^{n}\lambda_{j}-\sum_{j=3}^{n}\lambda_{j}\Big)+\cdots+X_{t_{n}}\lambda_{n}\\
&=(W_{t_{1}}-W_{t_{0}})\sum_{j=1}^{n}\lambda_{j}+(W_{t_{2}}-W_{t_{1}})\sum_{j=2}^{n}\lambda_{j}+\cdots+(X_{t_{n}}-X_{t_{n-1}})\lambda_{n},
\end{align*}
in the second equality we used $W_{t_{0}}=W_{0}=0$.

Therefore, we can write the characteristic function as 
\begin{align*}
\varphi_{t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}}(\lambda_{1},\cdots, \lambda_{n})&=\mathbb{E}\exp\Big(i\sum_{j=1}^{n}\lambda_{j}X_{t_{j}}\Big)\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}\exp\Big(i(X_{t_{k}}-X_{t_{k-1}})\sum_{j=k}^{n}\lambda_{j}\Big),
\end{align*}
where the second equality was obtained using the fact that the increments are independent (so the sum in the characteristic function can become to the product of characteristic function).

**Now I want to use the fact that the increments are Gaussian to write out the formula, but the problem now is that we have the sum of $\lambda_{k},\cdots,\lambda_{n}$, and I don't really know how to deal with them...**

By the way, as what I discussed with **Nap D. Lover**, my final goal is to use the characteristic function to show the consistency of finite dimensional distribution, if there is another other way to show this, I will give up the current computation happily :)

**Edit 2:**

After some attempt, I derived a general result for my final goal: to prove the existence of Wiener process using characteristic function.

In the middle of construction, I happened to find a formula for more general characteristic  function --- as long as you have the independent increments, I believe this construction can work all the time by only altering a little bit.

This proof is a long one so I will post it by answering my own question.

However, I don't believe this proof is only possible way to show the existence, since my proof is clearly a little beyond what I asked.

So please let me know and please do not hesitate to post your proof if you have another one. I believe any new proof rather than the proof I am gonna give will be better one  :)

Thank you guys so much for your upvotes :)

Comment: So you want the CF of the joint RV $(W_{t_1}, \dotsc, W_{t_n})$ at the finite times $t_i$? Is that correct? What for, is it just curiosity or do you have an application in mind (just wondering)?

Comment: @NapD.Lover Yes. It is correct. For the purpose, I want to show the existence of Wiener process by combining the Komogorov consistency theorem and characteristic function. Let's denote the characteristic function of $W:=(W_{t_{1}},\cdots, W_{t_{n}})$ under the finite dimensional distribution is $\phi_{t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}}(\lambda_{1},\cdots, \lambda_{n})$, then if I have an explicit formula of it, I believe I can show that $\phi_{t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}}(\lambda_{1},\cdots, \lambda_{n})=\mathbb{E}e^{i(\lambda_{1}X_{t_{1}}+\cdots+\lambda_{n}X_{t_{n}})}$

Comment: @NapD.Lover It then follows immediately that the characteristic function is closed under the permutation of indices, and $\varphi_{t_{1},\cdots, t_{n-1}}(\lambda_{1},\cdots, \lambda_{n-1})=\varphi_{t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}}(\lambda_{1},\cdots,\lambda_{n-1},0).$ So the family of finite dimensional distribution is consistent, and the existence of such a process follows from the consistency theorem.

Comment: @NapD.Lover any idea about how to show? perhaps there is another way to achieve my final goal?

Comment: @NapD.Lover sorry I think the definition of $\phi_{t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}}(\lambda_{1},\cdots, \lambda_{n})=\mathbb{E}e^{i(\lambda_{1}X_{1}+\cdots+\lambda_{n}X_{t_{n}})}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me firstly introduce my final goal.

> I'd like to show that the Wiener process exists by using the characteristic function.

There have been many proofs using explicit constructions, but I'd like to have a measure-theoric one. To do this, we need Kolmogorov Consistency Theorem, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem.

However, the theorem is about the explicit measure, but I want now to play with characteristic function instead. There are equivalent conditions for characteristic functions to show that a family of finite dimensional distribution is consistent. (I will mention this at the end of my proof where I use the consistency theorem).

Now, let us prove!

Let $\{\phi_{s,t}, s,t\geq 0\}$ be a family of characteristic functions of probability measure $Q_{s,t}$ on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ with $s,t\geq 0$. That is, for $z\in\mathbb{R}$ and $s,t\geq 0$, we have that $$\varphi_{s,t}(z)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{izx}Q_{s,t}(dx).$$

Now we need a lemma:

> Lemma: There exists a stochastic process $X=(X_{t})_{t\geq 0}$ with independent increments and has the property that for all $s,t\geq 0$ the characteristic function of $X_{t}-X_{s}$ is equal to $\varphi_{s,t}$ if and only if $$\varphi_{s,t}=\varphi_{s,u}\varphi_{u,t}$$ for all $0\leq s<u<t<\infty$.

---

*Proof of Lemma:*

$(\Rightarrow)$. This direction is immediate since $X_{t}-X_{s}=(X_{t}-X_{u})+(X_{u}-X_{s}):=Y_{1}+Y_{2}$. But $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$ are independent, so $$\varphi_{s,t}=\varphi_{Y_{1}+Y_{2}}=\varphi_{Y_{1}}\varphi_{Y_{2}}=\varphi_{u,t}\varphi_{s,u}.$$

$(\Leftarrow)$. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $0=t_{0}<t_{1}<\cdots<t_{n}<\infty$, $Y:=(X_{t_{0}}, X_{t_{1}}-X_{t_{0}},\cdots, X_{t_{n}}-X_{t_{n-1}})^\intercal$ and $z:=(z_{0},\cdots, z_{n})$, then using the independence of increments yields us $$\varphi_{Y}(z_{0},z_{1},\cdots, z_{n})=\mathbb{E}e^{i<z,Y>}=\varphi_{X_{t_{0}}}(z_{0})\varphi_{t_{0},t_{1}}(z_{1})\cdots \varphi_{t_{n-1},t_{n}}(z_{n}),$$ where the distribution of $X_{t_{0}}$ is an arbitrary probability measure $Q_{0}$ on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

For $X_{t_{0},\cdots, t_{n}}=(X_{t_{0}},\cdots, X_{t_{n}})^{\intercal}$, we have that $X_{t_{0},\cdots, t_{n}}=AY$ where $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
1 & 1 & 0 &  \cdots & 0 \\ 
 1& 1 & 1 & \cdots &0 \\ 
 \cdots& \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots\\ 
 1& 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix}$,
and thus we have $$\varphi_{X_{t_{0},\cdots, t_{1}}}(z)=\varphi_{AY}(z)=\mathbb{E}e^{i<z,AY>}=\mathbb{E}e^{i<A^{\intercal}z, T>}=\varphi_{Y}(A^{\intercal}z).$$

It then follows that the finite dimensional distribution of $X_{t_{0},\cdots, t_{1}}$ has the characteristic function $$\varphi_{X_{t_{0},\cdots, t_{n}}}(z)=\varphi_{Q_{0}}(m_{0})\varphi_{t_{0},t_{1}}(m_{1})\cdots\varphi_{t_{n-1},t_{n}}(m_{n}),$$ where $m=(m_{0},\cdots, m_{n})^{\intercal}=A^{\intercal}z$ and thus it has the expression that 
[
    \left{
        \begin{array}{ll}
  m_{0}=z_{0}+\cdots+z_{n}\\
  m_{1}=z_{1}+\cdots+z_{n}\\
  \cdots\\
  m_{n}=z_{n}.
  \end{array}

Hence, $\varphi_{X_{t_{0}}}=\varphi_{Q_{0}}$ and $\varphi_{X_{t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}}}(z_{1},\cdots, z_{n})=\varphi_{X_{t_{0}},\cdots, t_{n}}(0,z_{1},\cdots,z_{n})$ hold for all $z_{i}\in\mathbb{R}$.

To show the existstence of such a process $X$, we just construct the family of characteristic functions $$\{\varphi_{t_{0}},\varphi_{t_{0},t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}},\varphi_{t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}},\ 0=t_{0}<t_{1}<\cdots<t_{n}<\infty,\ n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$ from $\varphi_{Q_{0}}$ and $\{\varphi_{s,t},0\leq s<t\}$ as above and therefore we have $$\varphi_{t_{0}}=\varphi_{Q_{0}},\ \varphi_{t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}}(0,z_{1},\cdots, z_{n})=\varphi_{t_{0},t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}}(0,z_{1},\cdots, z_{n}),\ z_{i}\in\mathbb{R},$$ and $$\varphi_{t_{0},\cdots, t_{n}}(z)=\varphi_{t_{0}}(z_{0}+\cdots+z_{n})\varphi_{t_{0}, t_{1}}(z_{1}+\cdots+z_{n})\cdots\varphi_{t_{n-1},t_{n}}(z_{n}).$$

Now we just check the consistency condition using characteristic function, namely:

(1) $\varphi_{t_{j_{0}},\cdots, t_{j_{n}}}(z_{j_{0}},\cdots, z_{j_{n}})=\varphi_{t_{0},\cdots, t_{n}}(z_{0},\cdots, z_{n})$ under any permutation $j:(0,1,\cdots, n)\mapsto (j_{0}, j_{1}\cdots,j_{n});$

(2) $\varphi_{t_{0},\cdots, t_{\ell-1}, t_{\ell+1},\cdots, t_{n}}(z_{0},\cdots, z_{\ell-1},z_{\ell+1},\cdots, z_{n})=\varphi_{t_{0},\cdots, t_{n}}(z_{0},\cdots, 0,\cdots, z_{n}),$ for all $z_{0},\cdots, z_{n}\in\mathbb{R}$ and for all $\ell\in\{1,\cdots, n\}$.

This first one is obvious, and the second one holds due to $$\varphi_{t_{\ell-1},t_{\ell}}(0+z_{\ell+1}+\cdots+z_{n})\varphi_{t_{\ell},t_{\ell+1}}(z_{\ell+1}+\cdots+z_{n})=\varphi_{t_{\ell-1},t_{\ell+1}}(z_{\ell+1},\cdots, z_{\ell}),$$ for all $\ell\in\{1,\cdots, n\}$.

The existence of $X$ follows immediately from the Kolmogorov Consistency Theorem.

---

*Proof of my goal:*

Now to prove the existence of Wiener process $W$, we use the independent Gaussian increments to yield us $$\varphi_{s,t}(z)=\mathbb{E}e^{iz(W_{t}-W_{s})}=e^{-\frac{(t-s)z^{2}}{2}},\ \ \varphi_{s,u}=\mathbb{E}e^{iz(W_{u}-W_{s})}=e^{-\frac{(u-s)z^{2}}{2}}, \varphi_{u,t}=\mathbb{E}e^{iz(W_{t}-W_{u})}=e^{-\frac{(u-t)z^{2}}{2}},$$ and it is easy to see that for all $0\leq s<u<t$, $$e^{-\frac{(u-t)z^{2}}{2}}e^{-\frac{(u-s)z^{2}}{2}}=e^{-\frac{(t-s)z^{2}}{2}},$$ which implies that $$\varphi_{s,u}(z)\varphi_{u,t}(z)=\varphi_{s,t}(z)\ \text{for all}\ z\in\mathbb{R}.$$

The result follows immediately from the lemma.

**To "close" this post, I am gonna accept my own answer for now. But I will definitely change to accept someone else's answer if there is a new proof.**